# Am i using the hardware driver while using system call read/write?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, i2c, read-write

i have connected a hardware to an embedded linux board on i2c lines.
I can see the device at /dev/i2c-1

```
    filename = "/dev/i2c-1"
    filehandle = open(filename,O_RDWR);
    write(filehandle, <buffer to be written>, <number of Bytes>)

(similiarly for  read =   read(filehandle, <buffer to be read in an array>, <number of Bytes>)
```

Now my question here is am I using the Linux's i2c-drivers ( read/write) when I am invoking write system calls (and read like above using filehandle).

Also is this implementation independent of i2c module?I verified only after I do modprobe i2c_dev I can see my code running.
Is modprobe i2c_dev loading the i2c module and forming the /dev/i2c-1 in the /dev directory since I have connected the i2c device to it.

Comment: Can you provide [minimal reproducible example](http://sscce.org/)? And also what is the main question here?

Comment: OK , I have updated the Qs with the example !

Comment: thanks for the explanation!!.Can you please elaborate on how the write is associated with the i2c drivers here.(i mean i2c read/write).Where can I look for this association?I am not able to like this read/write with i2c drivers read/write.

Comment: I addressed all your questions in new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### User-space interface to I2C

User-space interface to I2C subsystem is provided via `/dev/i2c-*` files and documented at [Documentation/i2c/dev-interface](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/i2c/dev-interface). There are two ways to send I2C message:

- send plain buffer via `write()`; you need to include [linux/i2c-dev.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/i2c-dev.h) for this
- send `i2c_msg` structure via `ioctl()` with `I2C_RDWR` request; you need to include [linux/i2c.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/i2c.h) for this

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505023/reading-writing-from-using-i2c-on-linux) for examples.

### How /dev/i2c-1 is associated with I2C subsystem

`/dev/i2c-1` file is just an interface to I2C subsystem. You can send I2C message, receive I2C message and configure I2C using correspondingly `write()`, `read()` and `ioctl()` syscalls. Once you perform one of these operations over `/dev/i2c-1` file, it's being passed through [Virtual file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_file_system) to I2C layer, where those operations are implemented. Actual callbacks for those operations are implemented in [drivers/i2c/i2c-dev.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/i2c/i2c-dev.c) file, more specifically -- in [i2cdev_fops](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/i2c/i2c-dev.c#L527) structure.

For example, when you perform `open()` syscall on `/dev/i2c-1` file, the [i2cdev_open()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/i2c/i2c-dev.c#L481) function is called in kernel, which creates `i2c_client` structure for further send/receive operations, and that structure is being assigned to file's private data field:

```c
/* This creates an anonymous i2c_client, which may later be
 * pointed to some address using I2C_SLAVE or I2C_SLAVE_FORCE.
 *
 * This client is ** NEVER REGISTERED ** with the driver model
 * or I2C core code!!  It just holds private copies of addressing
 * information and maybe a PEC flag.
 */
client = kzalloc(sizeof(*client), GFP_KERNEL);
...
file->private_data = client;
```

When you perform some operations on that `/dev/i2c-1` file next, `i2c_client` structure will be extracted from `file->private_data` field, and corresponding function will be called for that structure.

For `write()` syscall the [i2cdev_write()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/i2c/i2c-dev.c#L161) function will be called, which leads to `i2c_master_send()` function call:

```c
struct i2c_client *client = file->private_data;
...
ret = i2c_master_send(client, tmp, count);
```

The same way `read()` leads to `i2cdev_read()`, which leads to `i2c_master_recv()`. And `ioctl()` leads to `i2cdev_ioctl()`, which just assigns corresponding flags to `i2c_client` structure.

### How /dev/i2c-1 is associated with hardware I2C driver

Operations performed on `/dev/i2c-*` file lead eventually to execution of I2C hardware driver functions. Let's see one example of it. When we are doing `write()` syscall, the whole chain will be:

`write()` -> `i2cdev_write()` -> `i2c_master_send()` -> `i2c_transfer()` -> `__i2c_transfer()` -> `adap->algo->master_xfer()`, where `adap` is `i2c_adapter` structure, which stores hardware specific data about I2C controller, such as callbacks of I2C hardware driver. That `.master_xfer` callback is implemented in I2C hardware driver. For example, for OMAP platforms it's implemented in [drivers/i2c/busses/i2c-omap.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/i2c/busses/i2c-omap.c#L1150) file, see [omap_i2c_xfer()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/i2c/busses/i2c-omap.c#L739) function.

Comment: Thats a well explained answer I have seen so far !!Thank!